# How to match a substring to a long list of keywords?

Tags: qt, qt5

Consider a function that compares searches the contents of a `QString` object for keywords that are a part of a list of keywords.  The keyword list is relatively large, consisting of a couple of hundreds of entries.  Currently I've been using a `QRegularExpression` object that matches all keywords (i.e., "(key1|key2|...|key199|key200)" and passing it off to `QString::replace`` but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to perform this sort of keyword matching?

Comment: Define "better"... That is probably a good way (as long as you create the regular expression once and use it until it need to change).

Comment: Linking hundreds of keywords in a long string literal doesn't seem like the most elegant solution.  It's effective but perhaps someone knows of a better way to pull this off.

Comment: @RAM, do you need to search for whole words or your keywords can be a part of a word like: `blabla keyword blabla` or `blablakeywordblabla`?

Comment: Can you add some examples with input data and expected output?

Comment: Google "radix trees". This seems to be a very common case in the text search algorithms and text editor implementations.

Comment: @vahancho the regular expression is used to match keywords within a specific context.  For example, to process strings to convert instances of "...foo.key1. blabla..." into "...foo->(key1). blabla..."

Comment: A regular expression engine will generate a pretty optimal matching tree for your expression. Just because your list of words needs to be concatenated into a regexp expression string, which then goes through regexp compilation step once doesn't make it inefficient, unless your list of words changes for every search. You will be hard pressed to out-do a regexo engine, which has been optimized over decades.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a lexical analysis problem.  Back in the olden days, we used to use a lexical scanner, [flex](https://www.gnu.org/software/flex/), to build lexical analyzing tables that were applied to the incoming text. This might be an approach depending on what you want to do with the results.